If $f(1)=f(2)=0$ then exist $c$ such that $cf''(c)+2f'(c)=0$

Problem. Let the function $f$ be continuous on $[0,2]$, second-order differentiable on the interval $(0,2)$ and satisfy the condition $f(1)=f(2)=0$. Prove that there exists a real number $c$ in $(0,2)$ such that
$$ cf''(c)+2f'(c)=0 $$

My idea is use MVT to prove that $f'(c)=\frac{-f(0)}{2}$ and use idea from the problem

If $f(0)=f(1)=f(2)=0$, $\forall x, \exists c, f(x)=\frac{1}{6}x(x-1)(x-2)f'''(c)$,

but I stuck at proving it. Can someone help me please, thank you.

First Method. Let
$$ g(x) = x f(x). $$
Then $g$ is continuous on $[0, 2]$, twice-differentiable on $(0, 2)$, and satisfies $g(0) = g(1) = g(2) = 0$. So by Rolle's theorem, there exist $\xi_1 \in (0, 1)$ and $\xi_2 \in (1, 2)$ such that
$$ g'(\xi_1) = g'(\xi_2) = 0. $$
Now, since $g'$ is continuously differentiable on $[\xi_1, \xi_2]$, Rolle's theorem again tells that there exists $c \in (\xi_1, \xi_2)$ satisfying
$$ g''(c) = 0. $$
Now the desired claim follows by noting that
$$ g''(x) = x f''(x) + 2f'(x). $$

Second Method. Assume otherwise that there is no such $c$. Let $g(x) = x f(x)$. Then by Darboux theorem and the identity $g''(x) = xf''(x) + 2f'(x)$, we know that either $g'' > 0$ on $(0, 2)$ or $g''(x) < 0$ on $(0, 2)$. In other words, $g$ is either strictly convex or strict concave on $[0, 2]$. Now it is evident that such a function cannot have 3 distinct zeros, a contradiction.

As a subsidiary question, try to prove the same conclusion if we assume $f(0)=f(2)= 0$ instead of $f(1)=f(2)=0$.

@Gribouillis I added a second method using convexity, and it can be adapted to solve your question :)

If I could upvote a second time, I would do it! My idea was actually based on Darboux theorem, but applied to the derivative of $x^2 f'(x)$ as in Lorago's deleted reply.

I also would have liked to be able to upvote SangchulLee's answer more than once. My motivation for the following variant is to salvage @geetha290krm's (now deleted) answer, from which I steal a lot. (Here, "increasing" means strictly increasing.)
If there is no $c\in(0,2)$ such that $cf''(c)+2f'(c)=0$, then the derivative of $g(x):=x^2f'(x)$ is of constant sign on $(0,2)$. Wlog $g'>0$, so $g$ is increasing.

Let us prove by contradiction that its limit $\ell:=\lim_{x\to0^+}g(x)\in[-\infty,\infty)$ is $\ge0$. If not, i.e. if $\ell<-A<0$ then we would have, for some $x_0\in(0,2)$: $\forall x\in(0,x_0)\quad f'(x)<-\frac A{x^2}$, hence $\forall x\in(0,x_0)\quad f(x_0)-f(x)<-\int_x^{x_0}\frac A{t^2}dt=A\left(\frac1{x_0}-\frac1x\right)$, which would imply $f(0)=\lim_{0^+}f=\infty$: absurd.
Now, knowing that $\lim_{0^+}g\ge0$ and $g$ is increasing, we can conclude: $g>0$ i.e. $f'>0$ hence $f$ is increasing, which contradicts $f(1)=f(2)$.

This ends the proof by contradiction that such a $c$ exists.

I could even prove that $\ell=0$ but that was not useful.
